# Отследить какая кнопка была нажата, если кнопки создаются программно

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте, программно создаю на форме кнопки в зависимости от того, сколько записей существует в базе данных по заданному запросу. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне определить какая кнопка была нажата, если я не знаю сколько их будет всего?
Заранее спасибо!

Создаю на WinForms

Comment: Если создаете кнопки программно, то создайте так же программно обработчики события нажатия для каждой кнопки.

Comment: Для начала укажите технологию, с которой работаете (WPF, WinForms etc.)

Comment: Да, забыл, создаю на WinForms

Answer (score 1):

Создавайте новые кнопки и обработчики события. Далее подписывайте ваш метод-обработчик на событие `Click`

```
Button myButton = new Button();
myButton.Click+=new EventHandler(this.ClickMethod);


private void ClickMethod(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Button but = (Button)sender;
}
```