# Вызов метода по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: c#

Требуется-при нажатии кнопки вызвать метод

```
public string Picha_SaveFile()
{
    saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "png";
    saveFileDialog.Filter = "Image files (*.png;*jpg;*gif)|*.png; *jpg; *gif;|All files (*.*)|*.*";
     if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
        return saveFileDialog.FileName;

     }

     return "";
}
```

Comment: В чём состоит вопрос? Как вызвать метод при нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642737/

Answer (score 1):

*Вы используете паттерн MVVM?* Если да, то:

```
private ICommand _someCommand;

public ICommand SomeCommand 
{
    get
    {
        if (_someCommand== null)
            _ledChangeCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(Picha_SaveFile);

            return _someCommand;
    }
}
```

В разметке XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="button"
    ...
    Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"
    CommandParameter="SomeParamater"
/>
```

Если же вы *не используете MVVM паттерн*, то всё намного проще. Создаете кнопку на форме, даёте ей определенное имя и следующий код:

```
btn.Click += btn1_Click;

private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //
    Picha_SaveFile();
    //
}
```